# Python: Average Prie per Year

Tags: python, list, file, average

Would anyone be able to help me with the below? I'm trying to create a program that can open the "notepad.txt" file and calculate the average price for the month of October.

```
notepad.txt
10-15-2012:3.886
10-22-2012:3.756
10-29-2012:3.638


infile = open('notepad.txt', 'r')

def clean_data():

    line1 = infile.readline()
    split1 = line1.rstrip('\n')
    items = split1[0].split('-')
    del items[0]
    del items[0]
    master = []
    master = master + split1 + items
    master = list(map(float, master))
    print(master)
    print(total)
    line1 = infile.readline()
clean_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

this prints and returns the average

```
def clean_data(infile):
    lines = infile.readlines()
    total = 0.0
    num = 0
    for line in lines:
        spl = line.strip().split(":")
        total += float(spl[len(spl)-1])
        num += 1
    average = total/num
    print(average)
    return average
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_data():
    n,c = 0,0
    with  open('notepad.txt', 'r') as infile:
        x = infile.readline()
        # for october 10
        if x[:3]=='10-' and x[6:10]=='2010';
            n += float(x[12:])
            c += 1
    print(n/c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Pandas:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

notepadtxt = StringIO("""10-15-2012:3.886
10-22-2012:3.756
10-29-2012:3.638""")

df = pd.read_csv(notepadtxt, sep='\:',header=None, engine='python')

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])

df=df.set_index(0)

df.resample('M').mean().values[0][0]
```

Output:

```
3.7600000000000002
```

Answer (score 0):

The following vanilla Python code should suffice:

```
infile = open('notepad.txt', 'r')

def clean_data():
    data = []
    for line in infile:
            data.append(line.strip().split(':'))
    values = []
    for value in data:
        values.append(float(value[1]))
    avg_price = sum(values)/len(values)
    print(avg_price)

clean_data()
infile.close()
```